# Does Borel $\sigma$-algebra cardinality equal cardinality of the continuum?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I know that cardinality of the  $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ is greater than cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Does the cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra equal the cardinality of the  $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes..if i remember correctly it can be proved by transfinite induction

Comment: @ Marios Gretsas, may you give the link to the proof of this statement?

Comment: You can google it... i beleive that exists a proof in this site also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard proof of this argument uses that the Borel sets can be produced through a transfinite process of length $\omega_1$: start with the open sets, iterate the process of taking complements and countable unions. One argues inductively that there are $\mathfrak c$ sets at each stage, and since $\aleph_1$ is regular and less than or equal to $\mathfrak c$, the equality follows.

One may want a proof that avoids any mention of $\omega_1$. This is possible working with codes (so you count codes for Borel sets rather than the Borel sets themselves; the "codes" are a way of keeping track of how the Borel set came to be starting from basic open sets). I sketched an argument in another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1770785/462) on this site, or you can see a recent paper with details along the same lines:

> [MR4003698](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4003698). Kánnai, Z. *[An elementary proof that the Borel class of the reals has cardinality continuum](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10474-019-00986-7)*. Acta Math. Hungar. **159** (2019), no. 1, 124–130.

Note that all these arguments by necessity use some form of the axiom of choice (eiher by arguing that $\aleph_1\le\mathfrak c$, or that a quotient of $\mathbb R$ has at most the same size as $\mathbb R$), since it is consistent with the failure of choice that the reals are a countable union of countable sets and therefore all sets of reals are Borel.